# CSS3 Transform Scale and CSS3 experience

Tags: html, css

Please in the comments bellow you can or you must describe what i did wrong or what should know before doing something with css3.

```
.img {     
    transform: scale(0.85);
}

.img:hover {
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

[jsfiddle.net/LPgtA/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/LPgtA/3/)

I think that using "transform: scale" property its a bad idea in ".img" class. But also I am worrying about that I skip something in html layout or using absolute positioning with a clearfix in the ".img" class it is also bad idea.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to know that did I use properly css3 properties. Thats all ;)

Comment: In order to say that we need to know you are trying to do in order to tell if the use is appropriate. No matter what you're missing vendor prefixed versions of "transform" though.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you so much! No way i did in the right way! Im so happy ;) Hell yeah) Now I can find a job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to add vendor-prefixed versions for the individual render engines.

```
.img{
-webkit-transform:scale(0.85);
   -moz-transform:scale(0.85);
    -ms-transform:scale(0.85);
     -o-transform:scale(0.85);
        transform:scale(0.85);
}
```